# p-form and Maxwell equations

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am reading "The geometry of Physics" by Theodore Frankel, and I have some questions about it.

I am really a beginner in differential geometry and I am more a physicist than a mathematician so my questions are probably obvious.

Here is the extract I don't totally understand [image]

First question : He says "the electric field intensity is a 1-form". I agree that in the work integral $E.dr$ is a 1-form but it is not "the electric field intensity". It is the infinitesimal work of electric field that is the 1-form. Indeed, I could imagine to integrate the electric field on a surface and then it would be a 2-form. So, is the sentence wrong or there is something I misunderstand ?

Also, they say $D^2$ is a 2-form version of $E^1$ (on the two last lines). Is there something special to understand here or just the fact that on $D^2$ and on $E^1$ I have the electric field components when I write the differential form. Is there really something to understand when they say "2-form version of" or not ? For me this sentence is just anecdotic so I think I miss something.

Also, after (not in the screenshoot I displayed here) they say that the magnetic field is a 2-form. I agree that in the Faraday law I integrate the magnetic field on a surface, so there is a 2-form behind it. But I could imagine to integrate the magnetic field on a line on another equation. So why do we say the magnetic field **is** a two form just because there exist one equation where it is integrated on a surface ? (it is a question really close to the one I asked about the electric field).

Comment: "I could imagine to integrate the electric field on a surface and then it would be a two form", "Also, they say D^2 is a 2-form version of $E^1$". I think you and the author agree. And yes, the magnetic field case is similar. I suspect by the end of the chapter you won't be wringing your hands over what kind of form the electric / magnetic field is, because you will have learned that we actually pack them both into an electromagnetic $2$-form that has superior symmetry properties (and work on spacetime rather than space). In fact, this section is probably meant as motivation for that.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ok ! So if I summarize I understood things well and I shouldn't pay too much attention to the way the author says it.

Comment: I would also point out there's an interesting thing here: notice that the fact that you can consider $2$-forms and $1$-forms the same is very particular to three dimensions. In the 'surface integrals' you always dot into that normal vector, but normal vectors are only a (uniquely defined) thing in three dimensions. In higher dimensions $n\ge 4$ there will be a relationship between $1$-forms and $n-1$-forms (Hodge duality).